# Github Action: s3cfg file is not found in /home/runner

Tags: github, github-actions, s3cmd

In my github action workflow, I want to upload a text file to s3. in my projects root folder I have created .s3cfg file

this is my `action.yml` file.

```
name: Github Action
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - fix/build

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Bootstrap app on Ubuntu
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12
      - name: Install s3cmd
        run: sudo apt install s3cmd
      - name: Install global packages
        run: npm install -g yarn

      - name: Install project deps
        run: yarn

      - name: Build the app
        run: yarn build

      - name: Upload a simple text file to s3
        run: sudo s3cmd put src/taka.txt s3://ashik-test -P
```

but, I am getting this error: `ERROR: /home/runner/.s3cfg: None
ERROR: Configuration file not available.`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're not quite sure where your repository code is mounted/placed in your GitHub hosted VM.

From the GitHub Actions Docs:
https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/virtual-environments-for-github-hosted-runners (the table I copied and pasted doesn't format well below so if you're confused, click on the link)

> Filesystems on GitHub-hosted runners GitHub executes actions and shell
>   commands in specific directories on the virtual machine. The file
>   paths on virtual machines are not static. Use the environment
>   variables GitHub provides to construct file paths for the home,
>   workspace, and workflow directories.
>
> Directory Environment variable    Description
>
> home  HOME    Contains user-related data. For example, this directory
>   could contain credentials from a login attempt.
>
> workspace GITHUB_WORKSPACE    Actions and shell commands execute in this
>   directory. An action can modify the contents of this directory, which
>   subsequent actions can access.

I just glanced at `s3cmd --help`

```
Usage: s3cmd [options] COMMAND [parameters]

S3cmd is a tool for managing objects in Amazon S3 storage. It allows for
making and removing "buckets" and uploading, downloading and removing
"objects" from these buckets.

Options:
...
  -c FILE, --config=FILE
                        Config file name. Defaults to $HOME/.s3cfg
```

It looks like s3cmd is looking for its configuration file at `$HOME/.s3cfg`, but since your repository is located at `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE` your file is really located at: `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE/.s3cfg`

I would try using the `-c` flag with s3cmd to specify the location of your `.s3cfg` file.
Ex:

```
      - name: Upload a simple text file to s3
        run: sudo s3cmd -c "$GITHUB_WORKSPACE/.s3cmd" put src/taka.txt s3://ashik-test -P
```

- btw I'm not sure why you need to use `sudo` here, my guess is you probably don't need it.
- Tip: You can use the GitHub action "Debugging with tmate" to "poke around" inside your runner/VM if you're confused about where things are or if you want to interactively try things. https://github.com/marketplace/actions/debugging-with-tmate